# Remove the ability of a role to modify publish targets

Tags: security, role-management

How can I disable/hide the "Targets" tab of the publishing restrictions dialog for a given role?

[image]

My role inherits from `sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing` and I found that I can disable publishing restrictions altogether by denying read access of my role (in core DB) to:

```
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish Restrictions
/sitecore/content/Applications/Content Editor/Ribbons/Chunks/Publish Restrictions/Change
```

However this now prevents users from controlling publish start/end dates and versions etc.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot disable this via user access. The only way to hide the target tab is to override the sitecore publish restriction UI. I have written an article on how to achieve this. The url is [here](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/04/24/sitecore-custom-publish-restriction/).

In brief, you will need to override the Sitecore UI Set Publishing. The path to this xml file is found at `Website\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\Set Publishing`. When overriding the xml file, you will need to copy the Set Publishing.xml to the folder Override found at Website\sitecore\shell\Override.

Then override the Onload method to disable the target tab. You can have a logic to disable it if the user is in certain role

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just deny the permission on the 
`sitcore/system/publishing targets`.
This way I thought users could see this screen, but they are not able to access the targets.

Comment: I still want the users to be able to _publish_ to any targets. I just don't want them to be able to mess around with the publishing target restrictions.